# В android studio 2.3.1 при создании переменой класса BigDecimal вылетает приложение в ошибку

Tags: java, android, bigdecimal

Не могу понять, почему при создании даже самого простого BigDecimal из строки вылетает приложение?

[image: в отладчике]

Конструктор, вроде, до безумия простой. Только начал изучать java и android studio и вот такой затык. Уже часа 4ре сижу голову ломаю и весь инет перерыл. Главное запрос в поисковик не могу вбить, т.к. не понимаю, что за ошибка. Эксепшен ничего не выдает

[image: после нажатия на F8]

и на вирт.устройстве выдает "В приложение Таком-то произошла ошибка.

Пришло время обратиться к вам, java-гуру!)

Comment: Приложите трассировку ошибки. Ака уберите ваш дурацкий `Toast` и поставьте туда `Log.e("TAG", "Error while bigDecimal", e);` - и потом с трассировкой сюда опять.

Очевидно, что дело не только в `BigDecimal`

Comment: Спасибо! Сделал. Ниже вырезка из лога и указание причины вылета программы на AVD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот навскидку могу 2 варианта назвать, можете поискать среди них свой:

1) Возможно Вы используете `BigDecimal` не из той библиотеки

```
import android.icu.math.BigDecimal;
```

вместо

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
```

или наоборот.

2) Если Вам всё таки нужно использовать библиотеку `import android.icu.math.BigDecimal;`, то для такого конструктора необходима версия API 24 и выше, а у Вашего телефона или AVD оно меньше.

Может поможет :)

Comment: Спасибо! Так оно и есть. Версия API у запускаемого AVD 19, а использую библиотеку 
import android.icu.math.BigDecimal;
Также трассировку исключения сделал и вышло: 
05-03 08:22:38.650 1996-1996/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.icu.math.BigDecimal', referenced from method ru.geo607.simpleburcalculator.MainActivity$7.afterTextChanged
05-03 08:24:16.080 1996-1996/? E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.icu.math.BigDecimal